# How to point streaming Dataflow at internal service?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am running a private service (e.g. Redis) on my Cloud Network, and I would like to access it from my streaming Dataflow job.  Is there a good way to configure my job so that, if I need to update the IP address(es) for the private service, I don't need to modify the Dataflow job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a layer of indirection to this setup using Global Load Balancing with Single Anycast IP (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/).  With internal load balancing, you can configure this target without exposing it to the Internet.